# PHP server for handling Server Side Events causes too many Apache connections

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache, server-sent-events

I have PHP server process which responds to server side events, think of it as a dashboard updating script.

It basically sends out data (JSON) every few seconds to a a dashboard page that makes use of SSE (server Side events) to display the dashboard. The issue is after a while the PHP process dies, but is re-spawned (this is part of the SSE protocol) , which is fine,  but somehow it leaves my webserver looking like this after a few hours...

```
 PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
 2954 root       20   0 22372  2140  1244 R  1.0  0.1  0:00.06 htop
 2952 root       20   0 70160  3584  2684 S  1.0  0.2  0:00.05 sshd: root [priv]
    1 root       20   0 10648   692   648 S  0.0  0.0  1:33.93 init [2]
  378 root       20   0 21348  1044   772 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.28 udevd --daemon
 1164 www-data   20   0  354M 16616  6200 S  0.0  0.8  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1165 www-data   20   0  354M 16616  6200 S  0.0  0.8  0:03.32 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1077 www-data   20   0  354M 16616  6200 S  0.0  0.8  0:03.35 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1115 www-data   20   0  356M 19704  6404 S  0.0  1.0  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1116 www-data   20   0  356M 19704  6404 S  0.0  1.0  0:02.87 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1079 www-data   20   0  356M 19704  6404 S  0.0  1.0  0:02.93 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1542 www-data   20   0  292M 18796  6516 S  0.0  0.9  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1543 www-data   20   0  292M 18796  6516 S  0.0  0.9  0:01.93 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1455 www-data   20   0  292M 18796  6516 S  0.0  0.9  0:01.98 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1811 www-data   20   0  360M 26516 12636 S  0.0  1.3  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1812 www-data   20   0  360M 26516 12636 S  0.0  1.3  0:01.87 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1669 www-data   20   0  360M 26516 12636 S  0.0  1.3  0:01.98 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1713 www-data   20   0  354M 13160  2992 S  0.0  0.6  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1714 www-data   20   0  354M 13160  2992 S  0.0  0.6  0:02.06 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1672 www-data   20   0  354M 13160  2992 S  0.0  0.6  0:02.06 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1879 www-data   20   0  356M 20292  6988 S  0.0  1.0  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 1880 www-data   20   0  356M 20292  6988 S  0.0  1.0  0:01.19 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 .. many more
```

First off, I know that PHP is not the ideal language to write these long-running (daemon like) background services and something like NodeJS would be more appropriate, but at this point in the development, it's not practical to re-write everything (ie. no budget) .

So my question is there some way to prevent Apache from spawning new connections  for these particular PHP requests or somehow re-using the a particular process to maintain this PHP script.. In essence caching the requests to a single Apache process when this SEE request occurs... Thanks

Comment: How does the PHP process "die"? Deliberately on your PHP side with an `exit`, or deliberately from the client side (deleting the EventSource object), or just the socket goes down?
How many clients do you have connected at the same time (normally, and at peak time)?

Answer (score 2):

By default, in JavaScript, server-side events have built in error handling. Part of this error handling includes reconnecting to the server if an SSE event handle is closed (either purposely or unexpectedly). The default reconnect time is ~ 3 secs. in most browser implementations according to this site: [HTML 5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/#toc-reconnection-timeout)

Per the link, the server, in its reply, can specify a retry time that the client should wait for before attempting to reconnect if you'd prefer to override the ~ 3 sec default. An example of that is seen below:

```
retry: 10000\n
data: hello world\n\n
```

**How does this help you?**

You may be wondering at this point how this helps you. Good question. As you note, Apache was not really built for persistent connections such as SSE or socket events. To accomodate this in your PHP, each time you sent back a reply of data, you can specify a `retry` header like the one seen above. Then at the end of the script call `exit`. PHP will finish, Apache will close the connection, but the SSE chain will continue once the *error handling* and *reconnect* execute.

It by no means is the most elegant solution. In fact, it's similar to a long polling approach using AJAX. However, you do have the built-in peace of mind that the browser will initiate the reconnect without you having to write custom handling and it still utilizes the SSE API structure, making it easier to port your server side code to something like *Node.js* at a later time (if desired) without having to modify your front-end code.

Note that this won't cache connections like you mention above in your question. It should help to alleviate your problem though by allowing Apache to clean up connections that are "waiting" freeing up those connections for new calls.

Comment: Fantastic answer, surprised it doesn't have more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

@War10ck's answer is good.

I'd also suggest [reducing KeepAliveTimeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#keepalivetimeout) to just a couple of seconds (if you need to serve many other files from the same vhost) or [disabling KeepAlive altogether](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#keepalive) (if it's mostly for SSE and you don't need performance for small files). This will allow Apache to "clean up" these connections quicker.